# Create Array Attribute In Java

Tags: java, arrays

So I understand the basics of creating strings and integers like this....

```
private String name;
private int min;
private int max;
```

but how do you set up an array?

For example, if I wanted to set up an array of book titles how would you go about that? If I wanted to set up an attribute like "books: book[]" would it be something like this?

```
private books[] book;
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: So my example it would be String[] anArray;?

Comment: You got it right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare an array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array of `Books[]` if you define the type (class) `Books`. For example:

```
public class Books{

    Books(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Books[] books = new Books[5];//an array of 5 objects of type Books
    }
}
```